# Spring Security not working on Weblogic 12.2.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, weblogic

I have a web application that uses **Spring Security**. It works on **Tomcat**, but didn't on **Weblogic 12.2.1.2**.

On Weblogic, user isn't redirected to the login page when tries to reach a restricted URL (for example localhost:7001/website/restricted/welcome). On Tomcat the user is correclty redirected to the login page.

I read that this is a **bug** of **Weblogic 12.1** and it seems to be fixed in Weblogic 12.2. But I'm using Weblogic **12.2.1.2** and I enconter the same problem.

I read some solutions, but I have difficult to understand them, since I have a different Spring configuration.

These are my classes about Spring Security.

This is the class that extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.

```
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
            public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
            throws Exception {     
                  auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                  .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                  .withUser("username1")
                  .password(passwordEncoder()
                  .encode("password1"))
                  .roles("ADMIN");                      
            }            

            @Bean
            public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
                  BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
                  return passwordEncoder;
           }     

           @Override
           protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

                  httpSecurity.formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/login")
                  .usernameParameter("userId")
                  .passwordParameter("password");

                  httpSecurity.formLogin()
                  .defaultSuccessUrl("/")                 
                  .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                  .and()
                  .sessionManagement()  
                  .maximumSessions(1) 
                  .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                  .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);

                  httpSecurity.logout()           
                  .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");

                  httpSecurity.rememberMe()         
                  .rememberMeParameter("rememberMe") 
                  .key("rememberMeKey") 
                  .tokenValiditySeconds(1800);  

                  httpSecurity.exceptionHandling()
                  .accessDeniedPage("/login?accessDenied"); 

                  httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()              
                  .antMatchers("/").permitAll() 
                  .antMatchers("/**/add").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")  
                  .antMatchers("/**/market/**").access("hasRole('USER')");                      

                  httpSecurity.csrf() 
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
           }                 

    }
```

This is the class that extends **AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer**.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
implements WebApplicationInitializer {

     @Override
     protected boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() {         
         return true;
     }

}
```

The problem seems to be bound to **Spring Boot**.
When, with **Spring Tool Suite**, I use the **Spring Starter Project wizard** (Spring boot) I encounter the problem.
If I don't use Spring Boot, Spring Security work properly!

How should I fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Make sure that the class loading is correct (as Weblogic ships with its own Spring version) so it should prefer application classes over server classes. Next AFAIK due to issues with class loading and type detection, you should also add `implements WebApplicationInitializer` to the `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` as only extending isn't enough. IIRC Spring Boot suffers the same when using an initializer like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help man. I edited my class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer, as you can see in the post. Is it correct?
When you say "Make sure that the class loading is correct..." you mean I have to configure weblogic.xml inside WEB-INF? What are the package I should put inside weblogic.xml?

Comment: At least all the `org.springframework` packages... Not sure what else is in there.

Comment: I tried, but the problem persist...

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, but are deploying to Weblogic. Are you taking into account the steps that are required for bootstrapping a Spring Boot application in that way?

Comment: @MDP I was dealing with somewhat similar issue with Weblogic. I am just curious to know if you were able to work this out. In my case, I had followed this example, https://github.com/okta/samples-java-servlet/tree/master/resource-server,  and implemented okta filter because spring boot version of SecurityFilter chain was not working even in Weblogic 12.2.1.4.

Comment: I have also encountered the same issue. Weblogic is returning error 500 instead of 401 (which is the correct response and what I am getting on my local machine).  Could someone please provide assistance in resolving this?